# Google Chart Column chart to take whole month space

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a google column chart which I pass in a month and a year, and format the axis to display it in the MMM yyyy format. But on the actual chart and the grid-lines, the google chart inserts a default day as 1. Therefore, the chart doesn't look nice.

I want a whole column to cover a whole month and am not sure how to achive this.

[image]

My code is

```
static drawChartIssuesPerMonthForCompany(data) {
    let dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn("date", "Months");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Issue Count");

    data.forEach(row => {
        console.log(data);
        dataTable.addRow([new Date(row.yearId, row.monthId - 1), row.issueCount]);
    });
    let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));
    
    let options = {
        title: "Monthly issues",
        hAxis: {
            title: "Months",
            gridelines: {
                count: -1
            },
            format: 'MMM yyyy'
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: { color: 'none' },
            minValue: 0,
            title: "Issue Count",
            format: '#',
            maxValue: 4
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a `"string"` for the x-axis, instead of `"date"`

```
dataTable.addColumn("string", "Months");
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
    let data = [
      {yearId: 2017, monthId: 2, issueCount: 9},
      {yearId: 2017, monthId: 3, issueCount: 2},
      {yearId: 2017, monthId: 4, issueCount: 8}
    ];

    let dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn("string", "Months");
    dataTable.addColumn("number", "Issue Count");

    let formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
    });

    data.forEach(row => {
        dataTable.addRow([formatDate.formatValue(new Date(row.yearId, row.monthId - 1)), row.issueCount]);
    });
    let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));

    let options = {
        title: "Monthly issues",
        hAxis: {
            title: "Months",
            gridelines: {
                count: -1
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: { color: 'none' },
            minValue: 0,
            title: "Issue Count",
            format: '#',
            maxValue: 4
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="detailedCharts"></div>
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay response i was in a meeting, i have tried your advice given here but i get the following error Uncaught Error: Invalid type, String, for column "Months". i am investigating to see why this is happening wandering if you have any idea?

Comment: did you fix the column type in the definition? --> `dataTable.addColumn("string", "Months");`

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad stupid comment i misstyped "string" as "String" this works will run some tests and mark as correct thanks for your time and help!